# Somehow I am doing something wrong on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, down-votes, feedback

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824591/hiding-methods-in-a-derived-class-c) on Stack Overflow.

This question is voted down. As actually all my questions are on Stack Overflow. It's only voted down without any comment and I have no idea why. IMHO, it meets the standards. The question is valid, code is compilable (well not due to the error, but hey), the problem stated and an effort is made.

Why am I voted down?

Comment: What other questions? Did you remove them or did you create a second account?

Comment: Did remove them but same account.

Comment: Don't delete questions just because you got downvote or two. Instead edit them and improve them so they get upvoted.

Comment: Didn't delete them due to down-votes but comments like, quote: "You've got a memory leaks", quote: "moron" and such after I asked why the down-vote, quite insultive. Now I asked it again, as stated by me: "One day all will be formatted well, give some slack". I.e. what I am getting now :). So taking this oppertunity to say thanks to all.

Comment: Be careful about deleting a significant number of questions. If you do you might end up with a question ban. Rather improve your questions if you can. If you received insulting comments, please flag them as such. Behaviour like that is never appropriate.

Comment: You can roll back edits, you don't have to manually type it again. However @kiamlaluno might have good reason for the edit so better ask him first before going to edit wars here.

Comment: oh, no edit war intended.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: perhaps a bit late but why the edit? It does make the question shorter but this way it keeps information wich is vital to others.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I edited the question because the sentence was not grammatical, and I still thinking that sentence is still not grammatical. It also added not necessary words (which is necessarily a bad thing), and the style on Stack Exchange is generally "go straight to the point." I am not going to make an edit war, though.

Comment: @JohnSmith That sentence is not grammatical. At least, it is a run-on sentence. If you want to say that, you should say "As I want to improve myself, and Stack Overflow, I am going to ask the following: Why am I voted down?" On Stack Exchange you don't generally use a phrase to introduce your question, such as in "I have a question: What time is it?" You just ask the question. Saying that you are asking the question because you want to improve yourself is (IMO) not necessary as that is implicit, or taken as implicit. I generally don't think users ask just to complain.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I see your point but here on Meta I feel like "relaxing" these strict rules. Personally I would go with "I want to know why I am  voted down so I can improve myself and thus Stack Overflow in general".

Comment: @kiamlaluno : Seeing the point too. Rolledback. I don't mind strict rules, for chat we have chat. Feedback would be cool on down-voted/closed questions wich are from new people. So they can adapt easier.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "Which is necessarily a bad thing" was supposed to be "which is not necessarily a bad thing"; when I write too fast, I get this type of typos. I don't usually correct a sentence because strict rules, but to teach to the OP.

Answer (score 14):

The question is not bad, but it can use some improvements:

- Keep to the point, there is a lot of text and that makes it hard to get to the question.
- Code samples are great, but show only those really needed for the question.
- Provide a title that matches the question, and do not include the tags.
- Try to avoid obvious spelling mistakes.

Comment: quote:"Try to avoid obvious spelling mistakes.", trying but it's not my first language and also I taught myself. No classes ever. Can't do much about this at this instance. The rest I've tried to improve, so I hope the one up-vote is valid now, thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith Use your browser's spell check. English isn't my first language either, but that ensures at least the most glaring mistakes are caught.

Comment: +1 for this. Also note that some people are more nit-picky than others and a single downvote should not be seen as discouragement. Now, if you get 5 downvotes, then chances are something *is* wrong.

Comment: @Bart: No can do, it will suck me into things I want to stay out of. Have my principles and did already way to much compromises. Here it ends (i.e. in general, in life). Besides, it's not in my browser and I won't downloading such. Editting is possible for anyone and on my part, that won't be wasted time.

Comment: Thanks @Ernest Friedman-Hill, to catch the irony and fix my obvious spelling mistakes.

Comment: @JohnSmith Not using a spell check as a principle? Well, whatever suits you I guess. But spelling mistakes do factor into the quality of your post and its evaluation.

Comment: @Bart: Indeed, but way offtopic here to clarify that. Am sorry for letting it pass.

Comment: @JohnSmith, you'll just have to put up with people who downvote badly spelled question, also on principle :)

Comment: @Bart, as I wanted to know how bad my English would be, I have given in. Actually - I am doing a very goed ;) job unlike some scholars these days.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, true. As I see questions voted up which where the same like mine (or worse) I couldn't find why. Also some got closed (not for being a duplicate). One was to broad but when splitting up, same happened. Closed or voted-down. Couldn't put my head around it.